# flask not reflect code changes in development mode (debug = True)

Tags: python, flask

I am running in Windows, Python 3.7.2 and Flask 1.0.2.   Always working in "production" mode with Debug On.   It has been working fine, and flask is able to detect my code changes and the app reacts to the code change.

Recently, i don't know what has changed on my computer that caused very weird behaviors.  When I insert the code to include `send_file(file_path/file, as_attachment = True, attachment_filename = "report.pptx")` so that I can download my ppt report dynamically generated in the app, the app does not react to the code change.  For example, if I change file name to "myreport.pptx", when I click the link in the browser, it still gives me report.pptx.    I deleted all the pychache files and restart the app. that did not help.

One thing that helps is when I stop the browser, stop running the code and wait for a few hours ( i am not sure how long), and start running again, the change may be reflected.

Edit: Thanks to Wombatz's comment, it turned out to be caused by the browser redirect caching.  I searched for solutions and found this link very helpful: https://arusahni.net/blog/2014/03/flask-nocache.html.

Comment: Maybe your browser caches the page. Try clearing the browser caches.

Comment: I tried clearing the browser caches. it did not help.

Comment: @wombtz Thank you for your comment. It actually was caused by the browser caches.  I found it by resetting the browser settings to default every time I change my code and it runs OK.   My followup quesiton is how do I make the Flask App force clear the browser cache, so that I will be able to send dynamically generated files to users.

Comment: You should not ask follow up questions in the comments, but rather create a new question after you have done your own research. Im not sure however if stackoverflow is the best site for this. Take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the partner sites.